# Не работает звук

Tags: linux, аудио, amd, gentoo, radeon

Есть звуковая карта ICH7 и AMD Radeon 4xxx со звуком по HDMI.

В ядре модульно скомпилировал все возможные кодеки и драйвера устройств.

В alsamixer:

> HDA Intel dont have any controls

так же и с Radeon.

Что к ICH7, что к Radeon прикрепился snd_hda_intel.

В граб пробовал добавлять и `radeon.audio=1`, и `radeon.audio=0`, ничего не помогает.

Как быть?

Kernel 4.0.2, Gentoo.

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 3662
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
  Subsystem: Hightech Information System Ltd. Device aa38
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

[Конфиг ядра](http://rghost.net/7zYxjhm7C)

Comment: Поставить pulseaudio попробуй

Answer (score 1):

в подобных случаях имеет смысл скачать live-дистрибутив с наибольшим количеством вкомпилированного в саму программу *linux* (или в её модули) кода для работы с аппаратурой — например, какую-нибудь из последних версий *ubuntu*.

и, если и там звук не заработает, то разбираться уже с самой аппаратурой.

а если заработает, то выяснить, что должно быть скомпилировано и как сконфигурировано, чтобы заработало и в вашем дистрибутиве.

Answer (score 1):

1. В первую очередь решите правильно ли у вас все установлено:
   В `Gentoo Linux` существует два способа установить и запустить `ALSA`. Оба
   способа являются взаимно исключающими друг друга.
   а) Использовать `ALSA` драйверы, предоставляемые вашим ядром.
   б) Установить пакет `media-sound/alsa-driver`.
2. Для настройки ALSA используйте alsamixer, самая распространенная ошибка замьюченный канал Master. Используя стрелочки ← и → выберите "Master" и нажмите клавишу m.
3. Проверьте звук. Рекомендую `speaker-test -c 2`